# Symfony console - displaying help for command with no arguments

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

I'm developing a pretty simple Symfony console application. It has just one command with one argument, and a few options.

I followed [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/single_command_tool.html) to create an extension of the `Application` class.

This is the normal usage for the app, and it works fine:
`php application <argument>`

This also works fine (argument with options):
`php application.php <argument> --some-option`

If someone runs `php application.php` without any arguments or options, I want it to run as though the user had run `php application.php --help`.

I do have a working solution but it isn't optimal and is perhaps slightly brittle. In my extended `Application` class, I overrode the `run()` method as follows:

```
/**
 * Override parent method so that --help options is used when app is called with no arguments or options
 *
 * @param InputInterface|null $input
 * @param OutputInterface|null $output
 * @return int
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function run(InputInterface $input = null, OutputInterface $output = null)
{
    if ($input === null) {
        if (count($_SERVER["argv"]) <= 1) {
            $args = array_merge($_SERVER["argv"], ["--help"]);
            $input = new ArgvInput($args);
        }
    }
    return parent::run($input, $output);
}
```

By default, `Application::run()` is called with a null `InputInterface`, so here I figured I could just check the raw value of the arguments and forcefully add a help option to pass to the parent method.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: i think your solution is just fine, why you think it´s brittle ?

Comment: I don't like that it works outside of the existing input abstractions. It's also not the most readable code. If you see something like `if ($this->hasNoArguments()) { $this->addOption("help", true) }`, it's more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a specific action depending on command, you can use an `EventListener` which is called when the `onConsoleCommand` is fired.

The listener class should work as follows :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\HelpCommand;

class ConsoleEventListener
{
    public function onConsoleCommand(ConsoleCommandEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getCommand()->getApplication();
        $inputDefinition = $application->getDefinition();

        if ($inputDefinition->getArgumentCount() < 2) {
            $help = new HelpCommand();
            $help->setCommand($event->getCommand());

            return $help->run($event->getInput(), $event->getOutput());
        }
    }
}
```

The service declaration :

```
services:
     # ...
     app.console_event_listener:
         class: AppBundle\EventListener\ConsoleEventListener
         tags:
             - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.command, method: onConsoleCommand }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer, while more verbose and requiring an additional class, is likely more of the "right way" vs my own one below because it abstracts things a bit better. When I get the chance, I'll test it and if it's right, accept your answer. I'm away this week so it may be a while before I get to it :)

Comment: You're welcome. My primary objective is that if people has the same kind of need, he can find an answer here. And now I know how use the built-in `HelpCommand`. So thank's for your good question

Answer (score 11):

I managed to work out a solution which didn't involve touching the `Application` class at all. To call the help command from within another command:

```
/**
 * @param InputInterface $input
 * @param OutputInterface $output
 * @return int
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\ExceptionInterface
 */
protected function outputHelp(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $help = new HelpCommand();
    $help->setCommand($this);
    return $help->run($input, $output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Symfony DescriptorHelper provides formatting options

See the [Symfony `DescriptorHelper` on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/7.0/Helper/DescriptorHelper.php)

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DescriptorHelper;

public function handle(): int
{
    /**
     * @var array<string, mixed> $options
     */
    $options = $this->options();

    $helper = new DescriptorHelper();
    $helper->describe($this->output, $this, [
        // 'format' => $this->input->getOption('format'),
        'format' => 'txt', // txt|xml|json|md|rst
        // 'raw_text' => $this->input->getOption('raw'),
        // 'raw_text' => false,
    ]);
```

- This allows you to format the help as `txt` (default) or `xml|json|md|rst`

This is how the [Symfony HelpCommand](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7.1/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/HelpCommand.php) renders help for other commands. We just pass the class instance to `$helper->describe($this->output, $this, [])` instead of another command.

There are around 100 methods available on the command class instance. It appears that `public function help()` is not defined, so this could be put into a separate method.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DescriptorHelper;

/**
 * Get the underlying Symfony output implementation.
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface
 */
abstract public function getOutput();

/**
 * @param string $format txt|xml|json|md|rst
 */
public function help(string $format = 'txt', bool $raw_text = false): void
{
    $helper = new DescriptorHelper();
    $helper->describe($this->getOutput(), $this, [
        'format' => $format,
        'raw_text' => $raw_text,
    ]);
}
```

This will allow you to call help in your command as needed.

Display standard CLI help:

```php
$this->help();
```

Display the help as JSON:

```php
$this->help('json');
```