# How to output to terminal options and its description from Laravel Commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

From Laravel documentation you can create your own [artisan commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#writing-commands) and add parameters with descriptions

> {--param= : description}

For example if user not enter a required parameter I want to show this parameter and it description like is defined in $signature property.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you want to show this parameter exactly?

Comment: On the terminal, similar to when you execute php artisan CommandName

Comment: Do you want to display all available options for a command? Or you want to display required option that user didn't enter?

Comment: All or only required options would be work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can display all options available for a command with calling it with `-h` or `--help` option:

```
php artisan yourcommand -h
```

To add description to parameters use this syntax:

```
protected $signature = 'yourcommand {someargument : Description of option}';
```

If you want to do that programmatically, create a public method in the command class:

```
public function help()
{
    // Display all arguments with descriptions.
    foreach($this->getDefinition()->getArguments() as $name => $description) {
        echo $name . ' - ' . $description->getDescription();
    };

    // Display all options with descriptions.
    foreach($this->getDefinition()->getOptions() as $name => $description) {
        echo $name . ' - ' . $description->getDescription();
    };
}
```

Then call it from your code:

```
app('\App\Console\Commands\YourCommand')->help();
```

Comment: I know this typed in the terminal, but that I'm looking for is do this from code not from terminal. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: It works to get all descriptions, but how to get names, too. In the code $name is not defined.

Comment: @omixam I've fixed that, so `$name` should work now. But you also can use `->getName()` method as you use `->getDescription()`.

Comment: There is a cleaner way to programatically show the help text; I've posted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the help text programatatically, you can use the base Symfony methods to achieve this easily from inside your Laravel command:

```
$help = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\HelpCommand\HelpCommand();
$help->setCommand($this);
$help->run($this->input, $this->output);
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206709/8472578).